# Book about a female protagonist travelling through space with alien creatures called the Leviathan

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, space-exploration

The main character of the book was selected to travel space with these aliens that also were able to act as spaceships called the Leviathan. They were helpful to Earth in fixing its problems.

As they travel across space, the main character encounters another species traveling with the Leviathan. She realizes that they help many different planets, not just Earth. The other alien asks her to identify a bond name or something like that, but she doesn’t understand what that is.

Later on in the story, she becomes closer to the Leviathan she travels with, and they identify as a combination of their two names. I have tried searching for books called Leviathan, but cannot find the one I am looking for. It is a standalone novel.

Comment: Roughly when did you read this book, and do you have any idea when it was published?

Answer (score 10):

It's very recent (2018) but this seems to match [*Honor Among Thieves*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2301198) by Rachel Caine and Ann Aguirre.  I found a [review](https://www.booksmoviesreviewsohmy.com/book-review-honor-among-thieves-by-rachel-caine-ann-aguirre/) that includes the following details:

- The protagonist is a woman named Zara Cole;
- The Leviathan are gigantic sentient space ships;
- The Leviathan "rescued earth from us" which sounds like fixing Earth's problems;
- The Leviathan have "bond names" with their favoured people, blending the name of the Leviathan and the person (so Yusuf's bond name with Artemisia is "Temiyus").

[image: Cover of "Honor Among Thieves"]

Note, however, that this is *not* a standalone novel, it is the first book of a trilogy.

Comment: I've read the book and can confirm it lines up.  Zara and the Leviathan Nadim bonded to become Zadim by the end of the book.